# Target class [App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies] does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-middleware

Laravel application that i am working on keeps on showing me this:

> Illuminate \ Contracts\ Container\ BindingResolutionException
> PHP 8.1.10
> 10.28.0
> Target class [App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies] does not exist.

This is the `web.php`

```php
Route::get('/', [ListingController::class, 'index']);

// Single Listing
Route::get('/listings/{listing}', [ListingController::class, 'show']);
```

Comment: What does the app/Http/Kernel.php file look like?

Comment: Does EncryptCookies exist there? If not did you delete it?

Comment: please check your `sanctum.php` config and and in `middleware` ensure the `encrypt_cookies` are pointing to correct middleware